# Regex capturing groups that do not match expression

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a string that can look like that `"focusin mouseover input.test test:mousover"`.

What i want to do is get the groups that do not match the expression `/\w+[.:]+\w+/ig`, so only the `focusin` and `mouseover` in this instance.

Edit: This is for javascript.

Comment: what should be matched for this string `focusin input.test mouseover 
 test:mousover focusout` ?

Comment: Is it JavaScript? Only in PCRE you may omit matches, in other flavors you need to use code to get what you need while omitting other matches. Btw, are the words like `test:test:mousover` valid? Are you extracting or replacing? If replacing, what with?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is for javascript yes, i didn't think it was relevant, my bad, and no, the example i provide is the extant of what can appear in the string.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the same thing `focusin` `mouseover` `focusout`, i wanted to basically NOT match my expression.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is not for extraction, i want to add a string after each group that do not match my expression.

Comment: Don't make it more complicated than you need to `'focusin mouseover input.test test:mousover'.split(/\s+/).filter(s => !/\w+[.:]+\w+/ig.test(s)); // ["focusin", "mouseover"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string and apply the regex on each piece.

```
var str = "focusin mouseover input.test test:mousover";
var newstr = 'addme';

str = str.split(/\s+/).map(function (s) {
    // if matched, do nothing
    if (/^\w+[.:]\w+$/i.test(s))
        return s;
    // otherwise add new str
    return s + newstr;
}).join(' ');

console.log(str);

// focusinaddme mouseoveraddme input.test test:mousover
```

Comment: Yeah that is what i was doing so far, split, loop, modify. But since i was starting to work with regex, i thought i would go all the way with it, if it was possible.